# Using theme references in XML drawables requires API level 21

Tags: android, android-theme, xml-drawable, android-api-levels

Is there a way to make following code compatible with lower API levels:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

    <item android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="1px"/>
            <solid android:color="#ccc"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The part: `android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` produces this message:

> Using theme references in XML drawables requires API level 21 (current min is 15)

Answer (score -1):

use `android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: This removes the design-time message but produces the run-time error: `<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable` on older APIs (I tested it on API 17 and 19).

Answer (score -1):

Create an attars.xml file under the values folder.

In the attars.xml file, create an item for selectableItemBackground:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="selectableItemBackground" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

In your styles.xml define this attribute with your drawable:

```
<item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/yourDrawable</item>
```

And then in your drawable file, reference the attribute:

```
<item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```