# Make a API-dependent reference to a theme-style

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme, android-styles, qualifiers

API 21+:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

API <21:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

How is it possible?

---

I know the solution that uses `"?attr/API_dependent_theme_reference"` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14335578/5318303). This doesn't work for *App Widget layout*, unfortunately.

Also, I know the solution uses `style="..."` for the `view` and multiple *style definitions in `values` and `values-v21` folders*. But looking for a way to directly assign the `background` property (especially as Android, unfortunately, don't support assigning multiple styles like CSS: `class="style1 style2 etc"`!).

Answer (score 0):

You can have two custom drawables

drawable/backround_name.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
</layer-list>
```

and

drawable-v21/backround_name.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately _"Using theme references in XML drawables" itself "**requires API level 21**"_. See [this unanswered post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41650820/5318303). If anyone can reply that question, so your answer will be a correct one automatically :) .